# Where clause check parameter value return a field is NULL

Tags: t-sql

I have a where clause like this:

```
Where m.Date_6 = Case  When @IsCurrentRequest = 1 Then  NULL Else  m.Date_6 End
```

@IsCurrentRequest is a bit parameter. I want to check if @IsCurrentRequest = 1 then return m.Date_6 is NULL otherwise return 1. I know this won't work because m.Date_6 = NULL is not working. How do I fix? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood correctly your question, but may be this condition is what you are looking for (without using CASE)?

```
WHERE @isCurrentRequest=1 AND m.date_6 IS NULL OR @isCurrentRequest=0
```

Anyway, when checking if a value is NULL, you can't use column_name=NULL, but you should use column_name IS NULL (as NULL is a "particular" value)

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator will return `NULL` if any of its operands is `NULL`, therefore your code will not work as intended.

Try something like this:

```
WHERE IIF( @IsCurrentRequest = 1, IIF( m.Date_6 IS NULL, 1, 0 ), 1)
```

Comment: I have tried that before and tsql returns error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'"